# Is it a crime to run away from spouse and child and declare it as separation?

Tags: family-law

Is this considered as crime in Canada to run away from spouse and child without meeting their expenses and paying house loan.

Comment: Related:  [In a marriage, can one spouse just run away and declare this a “separation”?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/23717/in-a-marriage-can-one-spouse-just-run-away-and-declare-this-a-separation)